# How to connect existing MYSQL with an XAMPP in linux server

Tags: mysql, lampp

In my server, MYSQl is installed and it has some databases.
I have installed xampp (LAMPP) in the server.
My problem is , now there are two mysql and it is clashing.
My xampp is in /opt/lampp folder
How to connect my old MYSQL to the LAMPP, so that i can use existing databases?
(Any change in php.ini file?)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your MySQL data from the MySQL/Data directory into the XAMPP MySQL/Data directory -- correct me if I am wrong but this is what I did on windows with WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Copied Mysql/data files from wampp mysql/data directory to
xampp mysql/data directory. After the copy is done, simply restart xampp mysql service and the tables and data should appear on phpmyadmin